# Capistrano using sudo git clone instead of git clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, capistrano, bitbucket

Here's my Capistrano file:

```
set :application, "mydemoapp"
set :repository,  "git@bitbucket.org:sergiotapia/mydemoapp.git"
set :scm, :git

set :user, "serg" # The user on the VPS server.
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/opt/nginx/html/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :keep_releases, 1
set :rails_env, "production"
set :migrate_target, :latest

role :web, "192.168.1.1"  # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "192.168.1.1"  # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "192.168.1.1", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
```

---

> The IP addresses above are obviously fake, I'm using the IP for my VPS
>   server in real life.

I ran this command, to verify that BitBucket is allowing me to access the repository:

```
sergiotapia@jarvis1:~/.ssh$ ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org
conq: logged in as sergiotapia.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

However, running `cap deploy` again, I get:

```
[198.211.101.99] executing command
 ** [192.168.1.1:: err] Permission denied (publickey).
 ** [192.168.1.1:: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    command finished in 1026ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /opt/nginx/html/demoapp/releases/20130601025656; true"
```

I tried using `git clone` from my SSH terminal, manually and it worked fine as expected. My project cloned to a folder properly.

It seems Capistrano is running `sudo git clone` instead of `git clone`. This is verified by myself running a `sudo git clone` in the same folder manually on my SSH. Same `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

Why isn't my Capistrano setting for `:use_sudo, false` being used?

Comment: You may be getting the same error in your experiment, but that doesn't prove "sudo" is the problem.  Are you sure user "seg" on host 198.211.101.99 can ssh to 192.168.1.1 with public key authentication?